# Can't read the Binary file While I using fread in C

Tags: c, binary, fread

I am having a problem with reading Binary data using fread in C.

So here is the binary file that I need the read.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qfK6.png

My problem is that file has normal text in five lines and I can't figure out how to avoid them or read them as text and when the binary part comes starting reading binary data.

Here is my code:

```
size_t num;
FILE *fp = fopen("binaryXYZRGB.nkt", "rb");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("HATA!!!\n");
    exit(1);
}

int counter = 0;
while(1){

    struct read a;
    num = fread(&a, 1, sizeof(a), fp);
    printf("%d-) %f %f %f %d %d %d\n", counter, a.x, a.y, a.z, a.r, a.g, a.b);

    counter++;

    if(num < 1){
        break;
    }
}
```

and read struct:

```
struct read{
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
 int r;
 int g;
 int b;  
};
```

I probably read something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYUbY.png

but I read this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbaqd.png

If someone could help me that will be great.

Comment: Was the file produced using a C program using the same `struct read`, compiled by the same compiler, for the same target machine? If not, all bets are off; the layouts of C data types and data structures are implementation-specific.  That said, the layout of a structure with just `float` and `int` will be fairly portable, but there is still a byte order issue.

Comment: Might the `.nkt` file have some header before the data, so that even if the bulk of the data is compatible with your `struct`, you're misreading the file? Where did you get this file? What documentation of the file's format are you following?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [don't post images of text as links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58510763/edit) and paste text in place of images. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kaz, The school gave me this file and Yes, it's a nkt file actually but I have some trouble with reading the binary part of the data. So if "ALANLAR" is "x y z r g b" the data that should read x y z coordinats defined as floats and r g b color codes defined as integer. So if that binary data was written like normal text it's should be like 100.950 100.450 100.230 1 5 10 or different numbers so I just want to avoid that header part how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

As I see in the screenshot and also confirmed by you, you have 5 lines of normal data before the binary data...
There are a couple of options available to us...both involve using "fgets" in tandem with "fread"..

"fgets" because it stops and also records a new line when encountered. This enables us to accurately position the file pointer before reading in the binary data using "fread".
The couple of file pointer positioning options are

- "ftell" along with "fseek"

  `OR`
- "fgetpos" and "fsetpos"

The code below, documents both approaches, but I have gone with "fgetpos" and "fsetpos".
Hope the comments are useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int n = 0; //to use in "ftell"
int i = 0; //as a counter
FILE * fp;
char array[100];//in case you want to store the normal characters received from "fgets"
fpos_t ptr;//used to record file pointer position in fgetpos and fsetpos
size_t num;

FILE *fp = fopen("binaryXYZRGB.nkt", "rb");

while(i < 5){//since there are 5 lines
  fgets(array+n,sizeof array,fp);//stores these lines in array
//n = ftell(fp);//use this with fseek, post 5 iterations "n" would be the offset 
  i++;          // of binary data from the start of the file.
}               

//fseek(fp,n,SEEK_SET);//can use this instead of fgetpos/fsetpos
                     //the offset "n" collected above is used
//printf("%s",array);//if array needs to be printed

fgetpos(fp,&ptr);//get the current position of the file pointer   
fsetpos(fp,&ptr);//set the current position of the file pointer

int counter = 0;
while(1){

  struct read a;
  num = fread(&a, 1, sizeof(a), fp);
  if(num < 1){ //have brought the break condition above the print statement
    break;
  }
  printf("%d-) %f %f %f %d %d %d\n", counter, a.x, a.y, a.z, a.r, a.g, a.b);
  counter++;

}
 fclose(fp);
}
```